# reconnect/resume websocket connection with netty

Tags: java, websocket, netty, nio

I am developing a chat server through **netty websocket**. Our client side is mostly browser based. 
What's happening is, when I refresh the browser it closes the websocket connection and losses everything and creates a new socket when browser is loaded again. 
Is there any mechanism which shall reconnect with my previous websocket session at server side.

I am planning to cache all user session and if received any connection close event from client side then without deleting user session information waiting  more 30-60s,in between  if server receive new connection request from same client(detecting through cookies id) then replacing by new session information.

My problem is if I do not remove session when server receive connection close event , other read/write operation through this session's channel creating problem.

Answer (score 0):

What I can understand from following is

> My problem is if I do not remove session when server receive connection close event , other read/write operation through this session's channel creating problem.

Your chat logic is tightly coupled with the channel/channel handler object.

If you can move the chat logic to a separate class which I call "Session" and have onEventXXX callbacks in that class and have chat logic on top of it (separate chain of classes may be), when there is a write operation, write the message using session.write(...). The "Session" have to delegate it to the underlying channel.

When the underlying channel is closed, you can keep the "Session" object for while and reattach with it's new channel.

To do this you might need to create a separate Netty handler called "SessionHandler" and process channel events/session creation.

Comment: thanks for your replay. i am managing user session through a session manager where i am keeping basic session information with clinet's channel. For any write operation, i am sending a message to a thread maintaing blockingqueue and doing write operation is it good to do write through a separate thread? again yes i am keeping the session of the user for a while and waiting for new channel from same client and replacing current channel.